# Python iteration slow - what can I do to speed it up?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to build a piece of code that will automatically calculate portfolio earnings and ending balance on a given dataframe that includes date, price (close price of each day), a binary indicator that says to buy or not, and the # of days that the indicator says to hold.

I have written something the works, but the issue is that it runs very slowly, which I'm beginning to understand is a known problem with python iterations. From what I've been reading, this can be sped up through vectorization or cython, but I'm not sure where to begin on either of those paths.

For context, this takes about 2-3 minutes to run on a dataframe of 250k rows, and I would ideally like to get it down to seconds if possible.

Here is what I have so far:

Import the following as a df:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    

df = pd.DataFrame({'close': {'3/1/2022': 100,
      '3/2/2022': 101,
      '3/3/2022': 102,
      '3/4/2022': 103,
      '3/5/2022': 104,
      '3/6/2022': 105,
      '3/7/2022': 103,
      '3/8/2022': 104,
      '3/9/2022': 106,
      '3/10/2022': 107,
      '3/11/2022': 104,
      '3/12/2022': 102,
      '3/13/2022': 103,
      '3/14/2022': 99,
      '3/15/2022': 97,
      '3/16/2022': 101,
      '3/17/2022': 98,
      '3/18/2022': 96,
      '3/19/2022': 95,
      '3/20/2022': 97},
     '#days': {'3/1/2022': 6,
      '3/2/2022': 4,
      '3/3/2022': 3,
      '3/4/2022': 2,
      '3/5/2022': 3,
      '3/6/2022': 10,
      '3/7/2022': 5,
      '3/8/2022': 5,
      '3/9/2022': 6,
      '3/10/2022': 3,
      '3/11/2022': 5,
      '3/12/2022': 4,
      '3/13/2022': 6,
      '3/14/2022': 5,
      '3/15/2022': 4,
      '3/16/2022': 3,
      '3/17/2022': 1,
      '3/18/2022': 4,
      '3/19/2022': 3,
      '3/20/2022': 2},
     'indicator': {'3/1/2022': 0,
      '3/2/2022': 0,
      '3/3/2022': 1,
      '3/4/2022': 0,
      '3/5/2022': 0,
      '3/6/2022': 0,
      '3/7/2022': 0,
      '3/8/2022': 0,
      '3/9/2022': 0,
      '3/10/2022': 1,
      '3/11/2022': 0,
      '3/12/2022': 0,
      '3/13/2022': 1,
      '3/14/2022': 0,
      '3/15/2022': 0,
      '3/16/2022': 1,
      '3/17/2022': 1,
      '3/18/2022': 0,
      '3/19/2022': 0,
      '3/20/2022': 0}})








ind = 'indicator'
days = '#days'
close = 'close'


df['trade'] = 0
df['balance'] = 0
df['availablebalance'] = 0
df['bet'] = 0
df['returns'] = 0
df['profit-loss'] = 0
df['endbalance'] = 0  

startingbalance = 100
betsize = 0.2
stop = 0

df.loc[df.index[0],'balance'] = startingbalance
df.loc[df.index[0],'availablebalance'] = startingbalance
df.loc[df.index[0],'endbalance'] = df.loc[df.index[0],'balance'] - df.loc[df.index[0],'bet'] + df.loc[df.index[0],'returns']

i=1

while (i < (len(df))):

    if (df.loc[df.index[int(i)],ind] == 1) & (df.loc[df.index[int(i-1)],'endbalance'] > 0) & (stop == 0):
        if i+(df.loc[df.index[int(i)],days]) > len(df):
            stop = 1
        else:
            df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'balance'] = df.loc[df.index[int(i-1)],'endbalance']
            df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'availablebalance'] = df.loc[df.index[int(i-1)],'availablebalance'] + df.loc[df.index[int(i-1)],'profit-loss']

            if (df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'availablebalance'] * betsize) <= (df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'balance']):
                df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'bet'] = df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'availablebalance'] * betsize
                df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'trade'] = 1
            else:
                df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'bet'] = 0

            df.loc[df.index[int(i+(df.loc[df.index[int(i)],days]))],'returns'] += (df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'bet']) * (1+((df.loc[df.index[int(i+(df.loc[df.index[int(i)],days]))],'close'] / df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'close'])-1))
            df.loc[df.index[int(i+(df.loc[df.index[int(i)],days]))],'profit-loss'] += (df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'bet']) * ((df.loc[df.index[int(i+(df.loc[df.index[int(i)],days]))],'close'] / df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'close'])-1)
            df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'endbalance'] = df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'balance'] - df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'bet'] + df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'returns']

    if ((df.loc[df.index[int(i)],ind] == 1) & (df.loc[df.index[int(i-1)],'endbalance'] == 0) & (stop == 0)) or (stop == 1) or (df.loc[df.index[int(i)],ind] == 0):
        df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'balance'] = df.loc[df.index[int(i-1)],'endbalance']
        df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'availablebalance'] = df.loc[df.index[int(i-1)],'availablebalance'] + df.loc[df.index[int(i-1)],'profit-loss']
        df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'endbalance'] = df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'balance'] - df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'bet'] + df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'returns']

    if ((stop == 1)) or (df.loc[df.index[int(i)],ind] == 0):
        df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'balance'] = df.loc[df.index[int(i-1)],'endbalance']
        df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'availablebalance'] = df.loc[df.index[int(i-1)],'availablebalance'] + df.loc[df.index[int(i-1)],'profit-loss']
        df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'endbalance'] = df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'balance'] - df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'bet'] + df.loc[df.index[int(i)],'returns']

    i += 1
```

Comment: Post code with code formatting, not quote formatting.

Comment: update, that looks better